# Include histograms in matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am doing my scatter plots in matplotlib and they are generating well. However, to display the correlations between x and y, I need to add histograms on both axes as subplots (like shown in this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/scatter_hist.html)). Since the code in the example is a bit complicated, so I am not able to follow how to get my scatter plots to have these. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from statlib import stats
from math import log

x1=numpy.loadtxt("a.txt")
x2 = numpy.loadtxt("b.txt")


x1 = numpy.array(x1)
x2 = numpy.array(x2)
x1 = x1.reshape(82,296)
x2 = x2.reshape(82,296)
x = numpy.vstack([x1, x2])


y1=numpy.loadtxt("c.txt")
y2=numpy.loadtxt("d.txt")

y1 = numpy.array(y1)
y2 = numpy.array(y2)

y1 = y1.reshape(82,296)
y2 = y2.reshape(82,296)

y = numpy.vstack([y1, y2])


plot = plt.scatter(y,x)
plt.grid('on')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.ylim(-20,1000)
plt.title('Scatter Plot')

plt.show()
```

Any help would be REALLY helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the code from [the example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/scatter_hist.html).

Locate the line

```
axScatter.scatter(x, y)
```

This creates the scatter plot. Compare it with your line

```
plot = plt.scatter(y,x)
```

They are basically the same except that the `x` and `y` are reversed. So to connect your code to the example,
Simply replace

```
x = np.random.randn(1000)
y = np.random.randn(1000)
```

(from the example) with your code defining `y` and `x`.

Comment: Gives this error: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 7585
    'this looks transposed (shape is %d x %d)' % x.shape[::-1])
UserWarning: 2D hist input should be nsamples x nvariables;
 this looks transposed (shape is 72 x 144)

Comment: This warning has to do with the shape of your `x` and `y` input. The warning should not stop your program from working; though it is signalling that something *might* be wrong. The `scatter` and `hist` commands really expect `x` and `y` to be 1D arrays. If they are not, matplotlib tries to convert it to a 1D array. So if you do not want this warning, rethink why you are sending 2D arrays to `hist` and `scatter`.

Comment: because the data i am plotting is supposed to be reshaped. Plus, the program is not giving out the chart with this warning - but your suggestion of keeping the example program same looks legitimate, and probably an easy approach towards the problem without getting into the formatting of the example program - which is a mess for sure. Thanks for your support and help. :-)